# error in stored procedure variable declaration

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query

```
create procedure pr_InsertFilterOnItemCreation
@zCategoryId int,
@zItemId int,
@zFilterid int
as
declare @productId int
set @productId = (SELECT convert(int,IDENT_CURRENT('item')))
if( @productId<>null)
begin
insert into t_lnk_cat_product_filter_item set   cde_catid=@zCategoryId,cde_productid=@productId,cde_filterid=@zFilterid,cde_filteritemid=@zItemId
select 1
end
```

I'm getting error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'

Comment: `if( @productId<>null)`: is never true because null comparisons are always undefined, and undefined is treated as false here. Use `is not null` or `is null` to test null values; former in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Your `INSERT INTO` statement should be written this way:

```
INSERT INTO t_lnk_cat_product_filter_item
      (cde_catid,    cde_productid, cde_filterid, cde_filteritemid)
SELECT @zCategoryId, @productId,    @zFilterid,   @zItemId
```

Instead of:

```
insert into t_lnk_cat_product_filter_item 
set cde_catid = @zCategoryId,
    cde_productid = @productId,
    cde_filterid = @zFilterid,
    cde_filteritemid = @zItemId
```

Answer (score 0):

why u want to go for set here, just insert the values if the table is empty or update the corresponding values

```
insert into t_lnk_cat_product_filter_item    
(cde_catid, cde_productid, cde_filterid, cde_filteritemid)                                                                                                                 values ( @zCategoryId, @productId, @zFilterid, @zItemId)
```

Answer (score 0):

either you do:

```
insert into t_lnk_cat_product_filter_item 
values(@value1, @value2, @value3)
```

or

```
insert t_lnk_cat_product_filter_item 
select @value1, @value2, @value3
```